# How many solutions does this polynomial have?

Tags: polynomials

If I have polynomial $f(x) = (x-1)(x-1)(x-1)$ it is a cubic equation but only one root of $1$. I thought the number of roots (real and complex) equaled the degree of the polynomial? Does the equation technically have three roots?

Answer (score 1):

An element $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is called a *root of multiplicity $k$* of a polynomial $p(x)$ if there is a polynomial $s(x)$ such that $s(a) \neq 0$ and $p(x) = (x − a)^ks(x)$.

The polynomial $f(x) = (x-1)^3$ has a root of multiplicity three.

A degree $n$ polynomial has precisely $n$ roots over the complex numbers, when the roots are counted with multiplicity. This is one way to state the fundamental theorem of algebra.